# importing numpy works with interpreter but not fully with pyscripter in python

Tags: python, numpy, import, python-3.3, pyscripter

I'm working with python 3.3 (x64), and pyscripter 2.5.3 (x64), numpy 1.7 for python 3.3 (x64).
When I import numpy in a script, I don't have all the functions of numpy available, only few of them (not a lot, and not array )? As if it doesn't manage to import all the file from numpy

If I use IDLE it works fine, same with notepad++.

Comment: To expand on what 'rubenvb' said, we can't really help you unless you show us some code that demonstrates the problem you're having.  In the meantime, all I can really do is take a stab in the dark: do you have a file called `numpy.py` in the same folder as the scripts that you run?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which Python engine you are using in pyscripter. The IDE offers a connect to its own internal installation of python and a remote installation (typically the version you had in place before installing the ide.You need to ensure pyscripter is connected to the remote engine.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue
check the path of the python in PyScripter.
It is in the Tools -> python path
check if it is referring to the correct path of python
if it doesn't correct it and hopefully it will work

Comment: Thanks. And after correction, a restart of PyScripter is needed. Just for info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with pyscipter. Try to import numpy using Python Shell

Comment: I am pretty sure its not - i use numpy extensively with pyscripter. so far not problems at all.