# trouble in installing the scipy and numpy

Tags: python-2.7, pyscripter

I'm using pyscripter 2.7 when i write

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
```

the color of the 'scipy' and 'numpy' don't be change and they don't be bold like other libs.
why?
do i installed them in true way?

Comment: I also installed scipy and numpy for python 2.7 too

Comment: Why should they change? They are just module names and not some reserved keyword. Anyways, what does color have to do with any of your coding?

Comment: I just thought maybe i didn't installed them completly .because in some pages for learning scipy their color have changed

Comment: That's just web formatting. Module Names don't have color in IDLE either. :)

Comment: Also check if the module is imported to the remote or local python engine (pyscripter is ultra cool as you can use both - very helpful to use remote engine as it keeps the variables in main created during execution accessible post run). See my response to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260971/importing-numpy-works-with-interpreter-but-not-fully-with-pyscripter-in-python/15956833#15956833